# Login for just one member in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, admin, membership

I am creating my own blog engine in MVC3 and I don´t want to register users to post comments and other things. I just want to have login page for admin (me) so I don´t want to implement membershipprovider. I just want to have login page and [Authorize] atribute enabled and then logout link. What is best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Authorize] attribute relies on HttpContext.Current.User IPrinicipal object to verify whether user is authenticated or not. If you don't want to implement MembershipProvider then you will have to implement some type of your own IPrinicipal object. Another solution might be to go with FormsAuthentication with a web.config setting that looks something like this:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880">
        <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
            <user name="admin" password="43206512b209ba29cb5c642edc85bdac133354fe"/> <!-- SecretPass -->
        <credentials>
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Hope this help. Regards.

EDIT: I used online SHA1 hash generator http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator

Comment: Thanks to you I found some articles about IPrincipal, I implement it and it is working, thanks very much.

Comment: Is this not giving a hacker your password and telling them how its encoded? I'm not an expert in security, so please forgive me if I am wrong, but surely hackers would be able to gain access easily with this information?

Comment: Well, in reality you are right. But web.config is never served if requested. This was just a suggestion to Bibo. However, if Bibo implements an object of type IPrincipal then this would not be required in web.config. Additionally SHA1 algorithm is pretty hard to crack, but still possible with brute force. Good point csharpsi.

Answer (score 0):

By using some hard coded password/user name or machine specific login (Admin module is available only a specific IP) is easy.

Comment: Can you give me link for some article to this solution? :)